# Laravel Echo: How to make other users join a channel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher, laravel-echo

Developing a chat widget using Laravel 5.5, vue.js and pusher.

How can I make another user join a certain channel when another user creates a conversation?

For example:

A user creates a conversation that includes itself(UserA) and UserB.
He does this by POST method, and it is accepted. When doing the POST an event is triggered and broadcasted.

```
broadcast(new ThreadPosted($thread))->toOthers();
```

On ThreadPosted, on the `broadcastOn()`it should be something like this:

```
return new PresenceChannel('chat'.roomID);
```

But the UserB is not on that `'chat'.roomID` for it to be broadcasted.
How can I tell UserB that a new thread is posted or how can I make him join the channel of the new thread?

I thought about making a global channel in which the event is send through but every user would get acces to it and I just want the users, within the new thread, to be notified.

Comment: Still not able to do it.

Comment: did you find a solution? i was wondering the same thing 2

Comment: Yes. I did find a solution. The problem was that I was looking at  "chatrooms" as the channel, and that was the wrong way. The correct approach is making each user its own channel. And within it control all the messaging traffic

Comment: not sure if this will work with my app. im trying to make an app where users randomly pair in groups of two and chat with each other.. i have no idea how to implement the pairing logic.. i just created an array that has all the users in queue and then i use that array to pair randomly but then idk how to make the paired users join the same chatroom

Comment: Do you have a table in which the paired users are stored? Lets call this table 'paired_users'. Within this table you store the id of both users. The users with id 1 and 2 are paired. Within the workflow of id=1 you join your channel 'App.User.1' (I think that's the default one). When you send a message you send it to the channel of the user that its paired with 'App.User.2'

Comment: the problem is i dont know how to implement it without users. im using socket ids instead.. i want the user to be completely anonymous (no sign up process). so you can sort of assume that socket ids are usernames i have basically created an array that has all the socket ids (users) connected to the lobby. but the problem is laravel echo is made to work with users not with socket ids as users.. i might just stop using laravel echo altogether and just use vanilla socket io with redis as i have no idea how to implement this kind of app in laravel echo (no usernames just socket ids)